# Segmentation fault with malloc "unlink"

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, malloc, new-operator

I am getting a segmentation fault that is internal to malloc. Here is the trace of the error via gdb (Note: everything frome frame 4 and above is my code).

```
#0  0xf7d109dd in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0xf7e45420 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=100)
    at malloc.c:3697
#1  0xf7d12358 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=100) at malloc.c:2888
#2  0xf7efb4a5 in operator new(unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0xf7efb5ab in operator new[](unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x0804f295 in GetDataFromMem (fileAddr=1744, size=-1) at ../userprog/exception.cc:709
#5  0x0804ec9d in ExecSC (bufAddr=1744, ptrAddr=2912) at ../userprog/exception.cc:578
#6  0x0804dde9 in ExceptionHandler (which=SyscallException) at ../userprog/exception.cc:191
#7  0x08051585 in Machine::RaiseException (this=0x805b8c8, which=SyscallException, badVAddr=0)
    at ../machine/machine.cc:109
#8  0x08052ee3 in Machine::OneInstruction (this=0x805b8c8, instr=0x80628e8) at ../machine/mipssim.cc:535
#9  0x080519d0 in Machine::Run (this=0x805b8c8) at ../machine/mipssim.cc:40
#10 0x0804e74f in ForkBootStrap (val=0) at ../userprog/exception.cc:462
#11 0x08054338 in ThreadRoot ()
#12 0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

The line in my code that resulted in the fault:

```
int vpn = fileAddr / PageSize;
int offset = fileAddr % PageSize;
int counter = 0;
bool nullhit = false;
char *buf;
if (size == -1)
{
int curSize = DEF_BUF_LEN; //100
buf = new char[curSize]; //SEGFAULT
```

The exact line where the segmentation fault occurred (within malloc code):

```
3687              else
3688                {
3689                  size = chunksize (victim);
3690
3691                  /*  We know the first chunk in this bin is big enough to use. */
(gdb) 
3692                  assert ((unsigned long) (size) >= (unsigned long) (nb));
3693
3694                  remainder_size = size - nb;
3695
3696                  /* unlink */
3697                  unlink (victim, bck, fwd); //SEGFAULTS HERE
3698
3699                  /* Exhaust */
3700                  if (remainder_size < MINSIZE)
3701                    {
(gdb) 
3702                      set_inuse_bit_at_offset (victim, size);
3703                      if (av != &main_arena)
3704                        victim->size |= NON_MAIN_ARENA;
3705                    }
3706
3707                  /* Split */
3708                  else
3709                    {
3710                      remainder = chunk_at_offset (victim, nb);
3711
(gdb) 
3712                      /* We cannot assume the unsorted list is empty and therefore
3713                         have to perform a complete insert here.  */
3714                      bck = unsorted_chunks (av);
3715                      fwd = bck->fd;
3716                      if (__builtin_expect (fwd->bk != bck, 0))
3717                        {
3718                          errstr = "malloc(): corrupted unsorted chunks 2";
3719                          goto errout;
3720                        }
3721                      remainder->bk = bck;
```

The values of `victim`, `bck`, and `fwd` in `unlink` are respectively :

```
(gdb) p victim
$6 = (mchunkptr) 0x805c650
(gdb) p bck
$7 = (mchunkptr) 0xffffffff
(gdb) p fwd
$8 = (mchunkptr) 0xf7e454e8 <main_arena+200>
```

I am not really sure what the causes for this are. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to figure what could be wrong with bits and pieces of code. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Probably you have problems in the program before this part (memory leaks, etc.) and for that reason get seg fault.

Comment: When you see a failure in a memory allocation operation, that typically means that shortly prior, memory was corrupted in some way. The most common such corruption causes are accessing an allocated area after freeing it, freeing an allocated area twice, accessing an allocated area past its end, and accessing an allocated area before its beginning.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks, then that might be the cause. My program has a lot of threads so now I know where to look for the error.

Comment: These kinds of errors are particularly difficult to debug in multithreaded programs. The failure occurs in the "victim" code that may not have any relationship to the "perpetrator" code. On the bright side, if you can accumulate a few such instances, you may be able to narrow down what they have in common. Definitely start with what this thread was doing shortly before this error occurred.